# Unable to return Cursor object - close() was never explicity called error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jdbc, cursor

Hey. I'm trying to return a cursor object to my activity where its gonna be used in a SimpleCursorAdapter, but Im having a **`close() was never explicity called`** error. I cant find any solution for this error, and I'm about to think that its a *non-solution error*, LOL.

Think with me.

The error says:

> close() was never explicitly called on
>   database
>   '/data/data/com.example.myapp/databases/myDB.db'

And has a warning too:

> Releasing statement in a finalizer.
>   Please ensure that you explicitly call
>   close() on your cursor: SELECT * FROM
>   contact_data ORDER BY duration desc
>
> android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException:
>   Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

The error is in this method, that is in the class DataHandlerDB (deals with database)

```
public static Cursor selectTopCalls(Context ctx) {

        OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(ctx);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); // error is here

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_2, null, null, null, null, null,
                "duration desc");

        return cursor;
    }
```

This method is used on my activity, by this following method:

```
public void setBasicContent() {

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view); 

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "listview " + listview);

    Cursor c = DataHandlerDB.selectTopCalls(this); // here I use the method
    startManagingCursor(c);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, new String[] {               
            DataHandlerDB.CONTACT_NAME_COL,
            DataHandlerDB.CONTACT_NUMBER_COL,
            DataHandlerDB.CONTACT_DURATION_COL,
            DataHandlerDB.CONTACT_DATE_COL }, new int[] {
            R.id.contact_name, R.id.phone_number, R.id.duration, R.id.date });

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "before setAdapter");

    Toast.makeText(this, "Before setAdapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

I try to close the cursor and database inside this method, but when I do that, the error is not fixed, and it doesnt print my list.

I tried to close it on the selectValues() method, but when doing that, it says, trying to re-open cursor already closed (*something like that*).

I also tried to close the cursor and database in onDestroy(), onStop() but it didnt worked.

Thats why I thought there were no soluytion for that. What am I supose to do?

The class **DataHandlerDB.java**, has a createDB() method:

```
public static SQLiteDatabase createDB(Context ctx) {
        OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(ctx);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        helper.onOpen(db);
        db.close();
        return db;
    }
```

And an Inner Class called **OpenHelper(extends SQLiteOpenHelper)**

```
public static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mContext;

        OpenHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.mContext = context;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String[] sql = mContext.getString(
                    R.string.MyString_OnCreate).split("\n");

            db.beginTransaction();

            try {
                execMultipleSQL(db, sql);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data", e.toString());
                throw e;

            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();

            }
        }

        private void execMultipleSQL(SQLiteDatabase db, String[] sql) {

            for (String s : sql) {

                if (s.trim().length() > 0) {

                    db.execSQL(s);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            /*
             * Log.w("My Database",
             * "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
             * db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME); onCreate(db);
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            super.onOpen(db);
        }

    }
```

So anyone can help me to fix this problem?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new OpenHelper in each of your static methods, instantialize your `DataHandlerDB` with the current context and have the class hold a variable populated by  `getWritableDatabase`.  You are creating multiple cursor objects created by different `SQLiteOpenHelper` objects and Android doesn't like doing this.

Check this out for additional info:  http://www.ragtag.info/2011/feb/1/database-pitfalls/

Here's how it looks to me like you're doing things...

```
public class DataHandlerDB{

    public static SQLiteDatabase createDB(Context ctx) {
        OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(ctx);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ...
        return db;
    }

    public static Cursor selectTopCalls(Context ctx) {
        OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(ctx);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); // error is here
        ...
        return c;
    }

}
```

This results in multiple concurrent `SQLiteOpenHelper` objects and multiple `SQLiteDatabase` objects and the locking situation you currently have.

Instead of doing multiple Static calls, make a DataHandler class that you instantialize with the consistent context and then make normal calls (instead of static ones):

```
public class DataHandlerDB{
    OpenHelper _helper;
    SQLiteDatabse _db;

    public DataHandlerDB( Context ctx ){
        _helper = new OpenHelper(ctx);
        _db = _helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase createDB() {
        ...
        return db;
    }

    public Cursor selectTopCalls() {
        ...
        return c;
    }

}

public void setBasicContent() {

    ...

    DataHandlerDB handler = new DataHandlerDB( this );
    Cursor c = handler.selectValues();  //.selectTopCalls()?

    ...
}
```

When you create this object, it will persist 1 `OpenHelper` and 1 `SQLiteDatabase`.  This should alleviate the problems with SQLite wanting the database closed before it can access it.

Don't forget to close the DB in the `onDestroy` method of your activity.

Comment: I dont get it when you say: instantialize your DataHandlerDB with the current context and have the class hold a variable populated by getWritableDatabase. Could you give me a clear example? Thanks!

Comment: I did just the way you told me to do. But it keeps showing the same error, but now in the line of the DataHandlerDB constructor:

 _db = _helper.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: @cyberrog you probably still have an open connection somewhere.  Have you closed all previous connections in other activities?  If you use the way I outlined, then make sure you also call `handler.close()` when you are done using the DB.