# If I open a cursor, then set it to null, will it close?

Tags: android

I have a cursor object, which I use to gather the users contacts. I would like to reuse the same cursor so I don't want to call cursor.close();. If I set the cursor object to null, will it be closed automatically or not?

Comment: it will not. And will take up space in memory till garbage collected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have explicit garbage collection. So, this sometimes causes memory problems as that garbage can build up.

Leaving a cursor open when you could close it is an example of something the automatic garbage collector could have trouble with. This might cause a memory leak which could kill your app unexpectedly

### WHY OH WHY

Cursors are pointers to memory which store your results. Marking a cursor as `null`, doesn't delete the data in memory which exists. It just leaves all your rows in memory without something pointing to it.

---

Please close your cursor or risk destroying the very fabric of the universe

Comment: This is especially true for external resources: Cursors and Files, eg., *must* be closed explicitly (or with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which simplifies code) to avoid potential complications and "odd bugs" caused by unpredictable (if ever) running of the finalizer. One manifestation of such not closing Cursors explicitly is a possible database deadlock due to not being able to release locks.

Comment: (But in any case .. the universe remains with its ever increasing entropy, possibly proven with the release one more buggy program ..)

Comment: Not to mention Android tries to help out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613996/unable-to-return-cursor-object-close-was-never-explicity-called-error?rq=1